# Check give dates between two dates and return 1 or 0

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a date and if this date between two dates then need to return 1 otherwise it returns 0.this is a function.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcDateBet] 
(
    @procDate datetime, 
)
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DateIn DateTime = '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @DateOut DateTime = '2022-08-20 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @returnval DateTIME;
    DECLARE @InsidePeriod INT;

    //In here need to check procDate is inside DateIn & DateOut.. If Inside it then @InsidePeriod should be 1 else 0
   

    IF(@InsidePeriod = 1)
    //Some Query Here
      ELSE
        //Some Query Here


    RETURN @returnval

END
GO
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#, jQuery or functions? Please tag questions appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcDateBet] 
(
    @procDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN @procDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-08-20 00:00:00.000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
END
```